# What do I need to do to program an MFC/STL program in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2019, afx

I've installed Visual Studio on my private PC, the version is "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019", version 16.1.6.

In order to prepare a job interview, I'd like to do some basic MFC/AFX programming, starting by the basic `CMapStringToString` example from [the Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmapstringtostring-class?view=vs-2019).
This, however, seems not to work, as I don't have access to the mentioned file `afxcoll.h`. Indeed: there is no file, called `afx*.h` on my PC.

Is this a limitation of my free downloaded Visual Studio installation, or is there any add-in, add-on, extension or whatever I can install in order to work with `CMapStringToString` objects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly install MFC support in Visual Studio - which you can do on Community editions:

1. Open **Visual Studio Installer** from your Start Menu
2. Click the **Modify** button
3. Select the **Individual Components** tab
4. Scroll down to **SDKs, Libraries and frameworks**
5. Check the various MFC/ATL options for various platforms